# Running a regression with a categorical variable where multiple options are allowed

Tags: r

I have a dataset like:

```
df = data.frame(Employee = c('John','John','John','Tracy','Tracy','Tracy','Sarah','Sarah','Sarah'), 
                EmployeeID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                Competency = c('agile','leadership','behavior','agile','awareness','analytical thinking','behavior','leadership','analytical thinking'),
                Rating = c(2,2,3,3,2,3,2,2,2),
                Performance = c(3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

*Competencies are unique to each role so 2 managers in the same role would have the same competencies, but 2 managers in different role would have different competencies*

I'm looking to predict what factors lead to increase in performance.

Would it make the most sense to dummy code the Competency column to "flatten" out the data structure so it's one row per employee and take the average rating per competency? This would lose the information around each competency. Is there a way to run a `lm()` without "flattening" the data?

Something like (pseudocode) `lm(Performance~Competency + Rating, group_by(df1$employeeID)`

Comment: I think you want to fit a linear mixed-effects model instead of a linear regression here. lme4::lmer() is the go to function..

Comment: Is performance measured once per employee? Or once per competency?

Comment: once per competency per employee. So if you have 5 competency you are trying to measure on, you'll have 5 different ratings for each.